# python - split and get the part of a str before the last occurrence of separator

Tags: python, join, split

I am trying to extract certain part of some strings. These strings look like

```
a = "1_2_3"
b = "1_2_3_4"
```

I would want to get everything of each string before the last underscore so:

```
"1_2"
"1_2_3"
```

I thought this line should work:

```
"_".join(a.split("_")[:-1])
"_".join(b.split("_")[:-1])
```

but it gives me the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'joint'

However, apparently, `a.split("_")[:-1]` is not a str but a list (I checked by `type(a.split("_")[:-1])`). Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: The attribute error would be raised because you made a typing mistake and then you might have fixed it and now it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you misspelled using `str.join()` as `str.joint()`.

For your usecase though, looks like [str.rpartition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) would fit better, removing the split-join loop.

```
a = "1_2_3"
b = "1_2_3_4"

print(a.rpartition("_")[0])
print(b.rpartition("_")[0])
```

Output

```
1_2
1_2_3
```

Comment: Ah you are exactly right! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

You got a good answer that addresses your problem that you should probably accept. But in case you want an alternative, you can make a slice of the string directly:

```
a = "1_2_3"
b = "1_2_3_4"

a[:a.rindex('_')]
# '1_2'

b[:b.rindex('_')]
# '1_2_3'
```

This works by finding the right-most index of `_` in the string and slicing to that point.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try `rsplit`:

```
>>> a = "1_2_3"
>>> x, _ = a.rsplit('_', 1)
>>> x
'1_2'
>>>
```

Or one with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "1_2_3"
>>> re.sub('_\d$', '', a)
'1_2'
>>>
```